# Weekly active or lapsing status in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, tagging

I want to see the status of a customer each week based on their activity.

If a customer has transacted in the last 7 days it should appear as **active** and if the customer has not transacted in 8-21 days it should appear as **"lapsing"**.
I have these values in my table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abOK4.png)

**Desired output refrence:**
Week# Customer_id  Status

Comment: And you want rows for every combination of week and customer_id?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a row for every combination of week and customer_id, you could create a large cross join of the distinct combinations of those two from your orders table, then match all orders back into that superset keeping the latest (that's before that date).

```
with base_table as (
  select distinct customer_id, week_date
  from orders
  cross join (SELECT week_date FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY((select min(order_date) from orders), CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AS week_date)
)
select base_table.customer_id, base_table.week_date, max(order_date) as latest_order, 
case 
  when DATE_DIFF(week_date,max(order_date),DAY) <= 7 then 'active'
  when DATE_DIFF(week_date,max(order_date),DAY) >= 8 and DATE_DIFF(week_date,max(order_date),DAY) <= 21 then 'lapsing'
  else 'not active'
end as status
from base_table
cross join orders
where orders.customer_id = base_table.customer_id
and order_date <= week_date
group by 1, 2
```